# How to avoid full disk usage while runnnig repair in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, repair

I am running repair with -pr option. The issue which we are facing that when we trigger repair disk space usage reaches 100% on some nodes. I know running subrange repair is one option but we have not integrated reaper as of now. Is there any other way we can avoid this scenario?

Comment: You can run it on a single table at a time, in case not doing it already.

Comment: Yes we are running one table at a time.  Looks like subrange repair is the only way out

Answer (score 1):

Good practice is to always have up to `50%` disk utilization in case scenario like this happens.

Your best option would be to make sure you have less than 50% disk utilization before you trigger repair. You can check for any snapshots and remove them after taking backup.